# equivalence of all norms implies normed space is finite-dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis

It is well known that if a normed space is finite-dimensional, then all norms are equivalent.
Does the reverse implication hold as well?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $X$ is infinite dimensional there exists a discontinuous linear functional $f$ on it. Define $\|x\|'=\|x\|+|f(x)|$ to get a new norm which is not equivalent to the original norm.

Comment: Can you explain why $f $ exists?

Comment: @infinity Let $H$ be  a Hamel basis and ${h_n)$ be distinct point in it. Without loss of generality assume that $\|h_n\|=1$ for all $n$.  Let $f(h_n)=n$, ($n=1,2...$) and $f(h)=0$ for all other $h \in H$. Extend $f$ by linearity to all of $X$. Then $f$ is linear but not continuous.